# How do you tell whether your question should be in EE, Arduino or SO?

Tags: support, migration, site-recommendation, site-crossover

I have come across many questions that are an Arduino/Electrical Engineering/Stack Overflow blend and am not sure which one to ask it on. This includes questions on debugging arduino programs controlling circuits, which I come across a lot, like [this one.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/why-does-this-make-the-led-flash-green?noredirect=1#comment14587_8017)

I originally asked it on EE, thinking about the breadboard and LED, but it was migrated to Arduino. How do I determine which site it should be asked on?

Comment: This sounds like a copout, but you ask where you think you will get the best answer (assuming it is on-topic there).  You thought it was best on EE, and someone thought it was better on Arduino because it was about Arduino.  This is also why we shouldn't be migrating on-topic questions to other sites just because someone thinks it would be "better" there.  It only confused people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Generally speaking

As a beginner in some of these fields, you're going to have to accept that you won't know whether the problem you're experiencing is due to an electronic issue, an arduino issue, or a programming issue.

This will come over time as you ask questions.

Until then, ask on the site you believe has the most relevance to the problem.

#### Specific to your situation

Given that you're working with simple Arduino projects (programs and circuits) I'd suggest, generally, that you post most of these types of questions to Arduino.

If you can remove the arduino from the circuit and still show the problem (ie, lighting the LEDs, for instance) then go to EE.

Programming arduino questions should go to arduino. Though they could be answered on stack overflow, as a beginning arduino tinkerer you'll find that the arduino experts will be able to more quickly understand and answer your arduino programming questions.